# Passing via segue, PFObject crash Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax-error, parse-platform, segue

I am lost with segue. I tried to do it through [this tutorial](https://www.parse.com/questions/pfquerytableviewcontroller-segue).

Everything is working but only one line write me error and I don`t know how to fix it.
Image with error:

[image]

TableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Parse/Parse.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>  {

    NSArray *colorsArray;
    NSArray *searchResults;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *colorsTable;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchDisplayController *searchBarController;


@end
```

TableViewController.m

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"


@interface TableViewController (){
}



@end
@implementation TableViewController


@synthesize colorsTable;

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"displayDetail"]){


        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



        UINavigationController *nav = [segue destinationViewController];
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = (DetailViewController *) nav.topViewController;
        detailViewController.exam = object;
    }
}



- (void) retrieveFromParse {

    PFQuery *retrieveColors = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Hracky1"];
    [retrieveColors findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            colorsArray= [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        }
        [colorsTable reloadData];

    }];
    [self.colorsTable reloadData];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveFromParse)];

    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;

    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(retrieveFromParse) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return colorsArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"colorsCell";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    PFObject *tempObject = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];;



     [cell.imageview setFile: [tempObject objectForKey:@"ImageURL"]];


    [cell.imageview loadInBackground];


    cell.cellTitle.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"cellTitle"];
    cell.cellDescript.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"cellDescript"];



    return cell;
}



@end
```

DetailedViewController.h

> ```
> #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
> #import "Parse/Parse.h"
>
> @interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
>
> @property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *exam;
> @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *descriptext;
> @end
> ```

DetailViewcontrolled.m

> ```
> #import "DetailViewController.h"
> #import "Parse/Parse.h"
> #import "TableViewController.h"
>
> @interface DetailViewController ()
>
> @end
>
> @implementation DetailViewController
>
>
> - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
> {
>     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
>     if (self) {
>         // Custom initialization
>     }
>     return self;
> }
>
> - (void)viewDidLoad
> {
>     [super viewDidLoad];{
>
>    self.descriptext.text = [self.exam objectForKey:@"TextView"];
>     }
>
> }
>
>
>
>
> - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
> {
>     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
>     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
> }
>
> @end
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I read from your code it is because you are using a normal UITableViewController. To be able to access the property "self.objects" you have to be using Parse's subclassed UITableViewController called "PFTableViewController". They have included the property "objects".

I can recommend this tutorial to get an understanding of the PFTableViewController

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-app-backend-parse/

If you want it to work without the PFTableView you can do the following:
I can see that you have an array called colorsArray and that you add the Parse objects into that array.

So instead of doing this:

PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

You can do this:

PFObject *object = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

I hope it works out for you!

Comment: Thanks! Now I finally fully understand to everything.

Answer (score 0):

Along with doing the tutorial which another answer here has suggested, perhaps you ought not to pass the PFObject itself...

Figure out and query whatever text you are trying to show in your detail view controller, retrieve it in the table view controller, then ONLY pass that (instead of a entire PFObject).

Comment: Thank you for everything, now fully understand to parse. Anyway I have to remake all my project because Iwas doing it on normal base, not Parse. Thanks